# EMF: How can I extend a create child command?

Tags: command, emf

Elements in the EMF model I am creating need to have UUIDs as identifiers. I need to extend the CreateChildCommand to automatically generate these UUIDs and assign them to the elements as they are created. I can't find any hooks in the command creation process that would allow me to add this functionality to the command. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Find the item provider adapter for the container of your elements. Override

```
protected Command createAddCommand(EditingDomain domain, EObject owner,
        EStructuralFeature feature, Collection<?> collection, int index)
```

Possible children will be in the "collection" argument.